# How to stop animation on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, jquery-mostslider

Here is my [site](http://noidaprop.co.in/zeeshan/plutome-website/). Image slider is working fine, but I want the last number to stay on the screen. Now it is in auto play. is there anyway to stop the animation on last number?

using [this](http://noidaprop.co.in/zeeshan/plutome-website/js/mostslider.js) js for slider.

Comment: Nobody will go through 1200 lines of code. Please narrow down.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i got solution just now..

Answer (score 0):

Just make this change in line no. 803

```
else{
     next = 1;
}
```

To

```
else{
     next = '';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change startAutoplay() function

```
    function startAutoplay(autoplay){
        autoplayinterval=setInterval(function(){
          if(autoplay == true){
            slider.next();
          }else{
            if(current == children_number){
              clearInterval(autoplayinterval);
            }else{
              slider.next();
            }
          }
        },settings.pauseTime + settings.aniSpeed);
    }
```

> After that, call startAutoplay()

```
startAutoplay(settings.autoPlay)
```

Comment: It can be useful if you using by setting autoplay : true or false

Answer (score 0):

Oh hey. Here's julian (creator of mostslider). Maybe I should subscript to the tag for my slider... Never thought it's used somewhere as there were no feedback messages or anything else.

I'm really sorry for not answering to your question.

I see you already got a solution. This brings me to another point for the v2.0.0 release. Add a public variable which provides the current slide and the number of slides. With this feature this task would be fairly easy. If you have more desired features, please report them in the git repo tracker.

All the best,
Julian